# Problem with wavy edges in pattern - equirectangular render/Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, panoramic

I have a problem with wavy artifacts on straight objects, when I render panoramic scene. It’s shown only in pattern floor and it’s more visible as it’s closer to camera, like it could be caused by images stitching point.
First, I thought there is a problem that the floor is 3d model so I baked it and I made that floor as a texture on simple plain. But that problem still existed.
I have tried various settings, playing with dithering, rendering that floor in bigger resolution and scaling down… Nothing changed.
Of course these artifacts are only visible in panoramic viewers, like in google images, panoraven or newest Photoshop. When it’s shown in regular image viewer, edges looks straight.
Did someone has that problem and know a solution?

**Edit:** There is a blend file:

[image]

[image: setting]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the .blend so it's easier for us to find an answer.

Comment: @ValentinWalter Ok, I uploaded file